# oracle - UPDATE SQL: how to update several times the same line

Tags: oracle, sql-update, sql-delete

I need to Update quantity of several books, before delete them.
the deleting happen with this code (oracle has a hidden column called ROWNUM)

```
DELETE FROM project.cart WHERE isbn = ? and ROWNUM=1;
```

to delete ISBN one at time (there are equal isbn in the table). but the update only works for one isbn. it should update several times the same line for all isbn found.

```
String sql3= "UPDATE PROject.book SET quantity=quantity +1 WHERE project.book.isbn in "
     + "(SELECT project.cart.isbn FROM project.cart) ";     

// this code work perfectly, but for one time.
```

I hope you can help me. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
String sql3= "UPDATE PROject.book SET quantity=quantity + " 
     + "(select count(*) FROM project.cart where project.cart.isbn = project.book.isbn) " 
     + " WHERE project.book.isbn in (SELECT project.cart.isbn FROM project.cart)";
```

Comment: return invalid table name. if i remove ("from FROM" one from) return: missing right parenthesis

Comment: @neo999 Sorry, there were two typos during copy-paste

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that if a book is in the cart three times it should have `3` added its `quantity` column?

If so, you need to add the count. When a row is included by the `WHERE` logic, it's included only once, even if it matched more than one of the criteria. Try a correlated subquery instead:

```
UPDATE book
SET quantity = quantity + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cart WHERE book.isbn = cart.isbn)
```

This query will run very slowly if there are a lot of `book` rows, so you may want to add your original `WHERE` clause to the end to limit the number of `book` rows:

```
UPDATE book
SET quantity = quantity + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cart WHERE book.isbn = cart.isbn)
WHERE isbn IN (SELECT isbn FROM cart)
```